# VS code - unable to change the color of class using "textMateRules" inside settings.json for java language

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode 1.81.1 and I already install all supported and required extensions for java accordingly to the VSCode documentation.

I am using Color Theme - Spacegray VSCode v1.2.6 Mihai Vilcu (Spacegray Eighties Dark)
and I want to make all class color yellow so using TextMateRules scope I have tried, but no 'Scope' is delivering consistent result by showing the same color to all class names.
When I initialize a class variable/object using a constructor :
A obj = A() so when I use parenthesis, then it consider that as a function and changes the color what functions are using.
Another thing is when I associate the class name 'System' with out.println() then it consider the enture System.out as a object or variable so what code I need to add in textMateRule block inside systems.json file

Following is the code I am using inside the user file systems.json.

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": 
    {
       
        "textMateRules": 
        [

            {
                "scope": ["storage.type"],
                "settings": {"foreground": "#ffcc66",}
            },
            {
                "scope": ["variable"],
                "settings": {"foreground": "#FFFFFF",}
            }



        ]
    },
```

[Here is the image of code editor where it is not changing the color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJSnz.png)

I already tried different scope for textMateRules, example "entity.name.type.class.java" but this is not recogonized by textMateRules, I am unable to find solution to specific this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to instead use semantic highlighting customization (assuming that you're using a language support extension that provides semantic highlighting for Java like the RedHat Java extension):

```json
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Theme Name]": { // TODO put your theme name here. remove this wrapper to apply all themes.
        "rules": {
            "class:java": "#ff0000", // TODO
        },
    },
},
```

If the theme you're using doesn't support semantic highlighting, you can try forcing it by changing your `editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled` setting or putting `"enabled": true,` as a sibling property to `"rules"` in the above JSON.